# Mapping class group and CAT(0) spaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory, mapping-class-groups, alexandrov-geometry

I hope the questions are not too vague.

1. Is the mapping class group of an orientable punctured surface $CAT(0)$ ?
2. Is any of the remarkable simplicial complexes (curve complex, arc complex...) built on a punctured surface $CAT(0)$?
3. Is there any "nice" action (say, proper or cocompact) of the mapping class group on a $CAT(0)$ space?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(1) [Bridson showed that](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0685) if a mapping class group of a surface (of genus at least 3) acts on a CAT(0) space, then Dehn twists act as elliptic or parabolic elements. This implies that the mapping class groups of genus $\geq 3$ are not CAT(0) (**Edit:** as pointed out by Misha in the comments, this was originally proved by [Kapovich and Leeb](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01445254), based on an observation of Mess that there is a non-product surface-by-$\mathbb{Z}$ subgroup of the mapping class group of a genus $\geq 3$ surface). On the other hand, the mapping class group of a genus 2 surface acts properly on a CAT(0) space (this is not surprising, since [it is linear](http://www.msp.warwick.ac.uk/agt/2001/01/p034.xhtml)). I think it's unresolved whether the mapping class group of genus 2 is CAT(0) though (this is essentially equivalent to the same question for the 5-strand braid group).

(2) The curve complex cannot admit a CAT(0) metric, since [it is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of spheres](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01388737).

(3) The mapping class group acts cocompactly by isometries on the completion of the Weil-Petersson metric on Teichmuller space, which is CAT(0). However, this metric is not proper (although as Bridson shows above, the action is semisimple, Dehn twists acting by elliptic isometries).

So I guess it's unresolved whether there is a proper action of the mapping class groups of genus $\geq 3$ on a CAT(0) space (where the Dehn twists act as parabolics). This is unsurprising, since it is unknown whether these groups are linear (a finitely generated linear group acts properly on a CAT(0) space which is a product of symmetric spaces and buildings).

Comment: Ian: This is theorem 4.2 of M. Kapovich, B. Leeb, Actions of discrete groups on Hadamard spaces, Math. Annalen, Bd. 306 (1996) p. 341-352.

Comment: @Misha: The published title is a bit different, "Actions of discrete groups on nonpositively curved spaces"

Comment: @Misha: Right, I thought of this proof (you use the observation of Geoff Mess that there's a non-trivial circle bundle over a surface?), but I thought it was only the case of smooth non-positively curved manifolds.

Comment: Ian: This is a general argument based on product decomposition of parallel sets in CAT(0) spaces.

Comment: Brady and MacCammond showed in http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4778 that the 5-strand braid group is CAT(0).

Comment: OK, thanks Carlos. I thought they had done the 4-strand braid group. I think then this should imply the result for $Mod(S_2)$, but I haven't thought this through carefully.